# xpath with following-sibling

Tags: selenium, xpath, automation

I want to access the table with classname 'table table-hover' that should be under the class=='box-title' that contains the text 'OODR Items for next 20 Days'. Can any one please help me out to get the xpath for this ? I tried with following-sibling but no luck. Thanks in advance.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div id="topTenSellers" class="box box-solid box-primary frontpageWidget">
   <div class="box-header">
      <i class="fa fa-group" />
      <h3 class="box-title">OODR Items for next 20 Days</h3>
      <div class="box-tools pull-right">
         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-widget="collapse">
            <i class="fa fa-minus" />
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- /.box-header -->
   <div class="box-body no-padding">
      <table class="table table-hover">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
               <th>Booking</th>
               <th>Item Start Date</th>
               <th>Site</th>
               <th>Supplier</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <strong>1</strong>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <a href="" target="_blank">(642143)</a>
               </td>
               <td>21/10/2017 00:00:00</td>
               <td>Ski</td>
               <td>OODR - Out of Date Range</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
```

Comment: please provide xml, not an image

Comment: Sorry added now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`following`](https://www.wwp.northeastern.edu/outreach/seminars/intro_2017-02/presentations/xslt/xml_and_xpath_14.xhtml) instead of `following-sibling` as mentioned `h3` and `table` nodes are not siblings:

```
//div[@id="topTenSellers"]//h3[@class="box-title" and .="OODR Items for next 20 Days"]/following::table[@class="table table-hover"]
```

Comment: Thank you  Anderson. It returned 5 elements. I have added [1] in the end then I got the element  which I need.

Comment: If there are several `table` nodes with same class names on page, you can also try `//div[@id="topTenSellers" and .//h3="OODR Items for next 20 Days"]//table[@class="table table-hover"]`

Comment: A caution @Neela, if you have a heiarchy with more than 1 of those elements, specifying [1] at the end could still result in multiple elements. 

Wrap your xpath in () followed by [1] to strictly specify a single element. 

`(//div[@id="topTenSellers"]//h3[@class="box-title" and .="OODR Items for next 20 Days"]/following::table[@class="table table-hover"])[1]`

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one element of that class name then either of these will work. One thing to note though, selenium can struggle with spaces in class names depending on the version and browser. If you find that is the case, then use multiple contains to handle the spaces.

```
//table[contains(@class,'table table-hover')] 
//table[@class = 'table table-hover']
```

If you need that the element as a child of that OODR Items for the next 20 days

```
//h3[contains(text(),'OODR Items for the next 20 days')]/parent::div/following-sibling::div/table[@class ='table table-hover']
```

This path uses your anchor point, "OODR Items..", then goes to the parent, then sibling, then to the item with the specified class name. Good luck!